# Ftp transfer the rsync-way

Tags: ftp, rsync

I'm downloading a logfile quite often from a ftp-server (which I'm not in control over, btw), and it seems rather rediciolus to download the whole file every time.

So I'm looking for a program (linux-ish) or Perl module that in a way combines ftp and rsync, and only "updates" the file.

The logfile is constantly growing.

Anything like that around?

Comment: see [How to use rsync over FTP](http://serverfault.com/q/24622/15186) on [sf]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Install curlftpfs (if on Windows, use cygwin)

# Create local mount path
mkdir -p /mnt/myftp

# Mount the destination ftp site using curlftpfs
curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp://myusername:mypassword@ftp.mydomain.com /mnt/myftp

# rsync inplace using append option
# use a long timeout value as the first long phase
# (the inplace comparison) takes a while
rsync -rzvvv --inplace --append --progress --stats --timeout=7200 /mnt/myftp/path/to/source/file.log /path/to/local/destination/file.log

# When you need to umount the ftp site
sudo umount myftp

# You can also mount from /etc/fstab by appending the following line
# curlftpfs#myusername:mypassword@ftp.mydomain.com /mnt/myftp fuse allow_other,rw,user,noauto 0 0

# References:
# http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/344/mounting-ftp-host-to-local-directory-on-top-of-fuse/
# http://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2007-May/017762.html
```

Comment: It's very inefficient compared to what lftp in mirror mode does

Comment: @CharlesB it may be inefficient but it can be scripted to run automatically. I can't see how you automate lftp/mirror?

Comment: @justinhartman have you checked http://serverfault.com/a/24833/15186? It shows how to do it automatically.

Comment: FYI: --append implies --inplace. No need to include the specific instruction to not create a temporary target file for the transfer. Comparisons are not affected by --inplace.

Comment: How do you install curlftpfs in cygwin? It doesn't seem to be in the repos. Also tried apt-cyg.. package not found

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't "resume download" work for your case?

Just pretend your transfer was aborted last time and restart downloading from where you stop

Answer (score 3):

As said in [How to use rsync over FTP](https://serverfault.com/q/24622/15186), [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) has a mirror mode that makes syncing far more efficient than curlftpfs+rsync