# Propagation of deletions with wget

Tags: wget

I managed to do a backup of my ftp website to my Synology, with the task manager, using this script :

```
wget -m ftp://user:pwd@example.com/folder/* -P /volume1/homes/admin/
```

Unfortunately, when a file is deleted on the ftp server, it will not be deleted on the Synology. Is it possible to do it with a wget option ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: No. You can keep old and new copy and compare them. But with `wget` only - no

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you have a script to do what I want using the task manager of my Synology ?

Comment: Please check this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338621/ftp-transfer-the-rsync-way